# How a stationary time series forecasts non-stationary values?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

In time series data, non-stationary data is first made stationary (Using Differencing or any other methods). We train the model using this stationary data. So how come model's forecast will be close to **original non-stationary data** (as model has been trained with stationary data)?

Answer (score 4):

Stationarity is an issue mainly for ARIMA models. The "I" in ARIMA stands for "integrated".

To make a series stationary using the ARIMA method, you difference it .

After the model is estimated and forecasts are generated, the final step is to (re)-integrate the series to obtain forecasts that are close to the original data.

This applies for other methods besides ARIMA, for example Neural Networks or other ML methods: If you use some transformation to normalize or stationarize the data, then the final step in the forecasting process will be to reverse transform the data accordingly.